# server connect server using serversocket and socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

is there any possibility to create a server based on java that connects to another server...my main objective is to have a main SERVER connected by a sub server that transfer data to the main SERVER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. Server is just a java Program. You might need to create two thread in this program. One to handle communication with clients and other to handle communication with sub server. (You need to create thread per sub server). In this thread you can send/recieve data to/from client/subserver.

MAIN SERVER
You Main server will be multithreaded with each thead dealing with individual subserver. Each thread will have socket which will be connected to respective subserver. By threading. I mean you will perform all read/write operation to/from subserver in the run method of this thread.

SUB SERVER
If you have single client then you need to create two threads. One to communicate with MainServer and other to communicate with client. Similar each thread will have socket connection of respective entity. In case of multiple client, you need to create multiple thread each to handle request from particular client.

We need to use thread because there will be multiple sub servers and multiple client running at the same time.

Comment: my problem rite now is that i am not sure how does socket acctually work with thread...from what i think now is like this, it is possible to have SERVER connect to SUBSERVER but then i have CLIENT connecting to the SUBSERVER and wanted to pass data to MAIN SERVER through the SUBSERVER...is more like a proxy but i am not sure how to use the socket obj from printwriter to pass the data from the SUBSERVER TO SERVER since there is another socket from CLIENT connecting to SUBSERVER

Comment: is there any example for this? a simple example perhaps? i still cant get the link between thread and sockets.. because i am not sure how to access thread and if i am not mistaken does the thread binds the sockets together? like 1 server 2 client. server accept 2 client 1 thread per client but does it has 1 thread + 1 socket of the client?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. However, if you're planning on making your servers accessible from the internet (as opposed to locally), you'll have to configure PAT (port forwarding) on your router. Though I wonder if you actually need a sub "server"? If the sub server's job is to exclusively communicate with the main server, you don't have to configure the sub server as a "server". You can make it function as a "client" to the main server, which is much easier. However, if you want the sub server to also be accessible from the internet, you'll have to configure it as such.

Links:

[Port Forwarding](http://portforward.com/help/portforwarding.htm)

[Java Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets)

Comment: my purpose of the SUBSERVER is to become a proxy for my CLIENT to pass data to MAIN SERVER...is more like this the structure i have in mind..

Comment: opps i accidentally pressed entered... is more to like this MAINSERVER TO SUBSERVER TO CLIENT...CLIENT sending data to SUBSERVER and send to MAINSERVER.. but i am not sure how to handle threads and socket right now cause i already have writen the program and i am not sure how to access the thread for the socket..

Comment: Threading is a rather difficult subject. Take a look at the "Java Sockets" link. Supporting *one* client should be simple, but if your server demands multi-client support, you'll definitely need to pay close attention to threading.